# Chrome gives bad event object on <option> click

Tags: google-chrome, drop-down-menu, clicklistener

When clicking an option in a `<select>` element, chrome is returning an event with most coordinates set to `0` and with a negative timestamp. Is this a chrome bug?

In Firefox everything works fine.

Here is a codepen to reproduce it
http://codepen.io/lazamar/pen/EKqMYV

The click event looks like this:

```
MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 0, screenY: 0, clientX: 0, clientY: -436…}
altKey: false
bubbles: true
button: 0
buttons: 0
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: true
clientX: 0
clientY: -436
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
detail: 0
eventPhase: 0
fromElement: null
isTrusted: true
layerX: 0
layerY: -436
metaKey: false
movementX: 0
movementY: 0
offsetX: -9
offsetY: -445
pageX: 0
pageY: -436
path: Array[7]
relatedTarget: null
returnValue: true
screenX: 0
screenY: 0
shiftKey: false
sourceCapabilities: InputDeviceCapabilities
srcElement: select
target: select
timeStamp: -13502108.235000001
toElement: select
type: "click"
view: Window
which: 0
x: 0
y: -436
__proto__: MouseEvent
```